# Java shutdown hook across different JVM

Tags: java, jvm, weblogic, shutdown-hook

Can i  attach java shutdown hook across `jvm` .
I mean can I attach shut down from my JVM to weblogic server running in different `jvm`?

Comment: No, you can't. Nothing in the Javadoc to suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The *shutdown hook* part is in [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).

The *across JVM* part you'll have to implement yourself, because only you know how your JVMs can discover and identify themselves.

It could be as simple as creating a listening socket at JVM1 startup, and sending port number of JVM2 to it. JVM1 would send shutdown notification to JVM2 (to that port) in its shutdown hook.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs any examples can you please  help me?

Answer (score 2):

The short anser is: You can, but not out of the box and there are some pitfalls so please read the section pitfalls at the end.

A shutdown hook must be a thread object [Runtime.addShutdownHook(Thread)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) that the jvm can access. Thus it must be instantiated within that jvm.

The only way I see to do it is to implement a `Runnable` that is also `Serializable` and some kind of remote service (e.g. RMI) which you can pass the `SerializableRunnable`. This service must then create a `Thread` pass the `SerializableRunnable` to that `Thread`'s constructor and add it as a shutdown hook to the `Runtime`.

But there is also another problem in this case. The `SerializableRunnable` has no references to objects within the remote service's jvm and you have to find a way how that `SerializableRunnable` can obtain them or to get them injected. So you have the choice between a [ServiceLocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) or an 
[dependency injection mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). I will use the service locator pattern for the following examples.

I would suggest to define an interface like this:

```
 public interface RemoteRunnable extends Runnable, Serializable {

       /**
         * Called after de-serialization from a remote invocation to give the
         * RemoteRunnable a chance to obtain service references of the jvm it has
         * been de-serialized in.
         */
      public void initialize(ServiceLocator sl);
 }
```

The remote service method could then look like this

```
 public class RemoteShutdownHookService {

    public void addShutdownhook(RemoteRunnable rr){
        // Since an instance of a RemoteShutdownHookService is an object of the remote
        // jvm, it can provide a mechanism that gives access to objects in that jvm.

        // Either through a service locator
        ServiceLocator sl = ...;
        rr.initialize(sl);

        // or a dependency injection. 
        // In case of a dependecy injection the initialize method of RemoteRunnable
        // can be omitted.
        // A short spring example:
        //
        // AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = .....;
        // beanFactory.autowireBean(rr);

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(rr));
    }

 }
```

and your `RemoteRunnable` might look lioke this

```
public class SomeRemoteRunnable implements RemoteRunnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private SomeServiceInterface someService;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // call someService on shutdown
        someService.doSomething();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ServiceLocator sl) {
        someService = sl.getService(SomeServiceInterface.class);
    }

 }
```

**Pitfalls**

There is only one problem with this approach that is not obvious. The `RemoteRunnable` implementation class must be available in the remote service's classpath. Thus you can not just create a new `RemoteRunnable` class and pass an instance of it to the remote service. You always have to add it to the remote JVMs classpath.

So this approach only makes sense if the `RemoteRunnable` implements an algorithm that can be configured by the state of the `RemoteRunnable`.

If you want to dynamically add arbitrary shutdown hook code to the remote JVM without the need to modify the remote JVMs classpath you must use a  dynamic language and pass that script to the remote service, e.g. groovy.

Comment: great design, but some people recommend avoiding serialization at all costs

Comment: @OlegMikheev Do you know why they recommend that?

Comment: with serialization you restrict yourself to exactly the same JVM version across all parties, and there are [so many things to keep in mind bout serialization](http://www.javajee.com/best-practices-for-serialization-in-java) that the "best practise is not to use it" (citing Bob Lee)

Comment: @OlegMikheev serialization does not restrict you to the same jvm version accross all parties. Otherwise exceptions accross different JVMs would not work (they are serializable). Of course the class that you pass through different JVMs must be binary compatible with the classes in that JVM. That's why you have to take care about the class's version that is deployed in different JVMs.

Comment: That's true in theory, but in real life [this kind of problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599217/how-to-get-rid-of-invalidclassexception-serialversionuid) happen periodically. In times of Java 1.3 serialization issues were a disaster, lately these problems are less common, maybe because nobody is using it? :)

Comment: @OlegMikheev I agree that the java.io.InvalidClassException occurs often, but I think that it occurs because pages like http://wiki.eclipse.org/Evolving_Java-based_APIs_2 are not read very close. :)